# Vector potential and gauge in electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics, gauge

In a paper by Zimmerman [JOURNAL OF APPLIED PHYSICS 114, 044907 (2013)], it is stated that the [Lorenz gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition) in electromagnetism is the only gauge with real physical meaning.
How do I reconcile this statement with the quantum electrodynamics, where gauge transformations are only mathematical tricks used to simplify the calculations?

Comment: It might be that Zimmerman means to say that the Lorenz gauge is the only one which makes a intuitive physical interpretation possible...

Comment: Lorenz gauge has the added benefit of maintaining manifest Lorentz invariance, as opposed to, for example, Coulomb gauge.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is meant by "real physical meaning" ? Gauge is a choice of potentials which are auxiliary mathematical functions. There are many gauges that lead to the same electric and magnetic field. Forces on charged particles are determined by electric and magnetic fields, values or choice of potentials do not matter.

Comment: @JánLalinský: Robert Zimmerman states that in the Lorentz gauge there is the possibility to transmit vector potential signals. http://www.google.com/patents/US20090034657, so the Lorentz gauge has 'physical meaning', while the other gauges don't.

Comment: I found no reference to Lorenz gauge. I did not read the whole text, but the statement "To date, there is no known technology reported in the scientific and engineering literature, which can unambiguously prove that the coupled electrodynamic potentials A and Φ (often referred to as the 4-vector potential) have any physical significance, i.e., that they are measurable." seems correct.

Comment: @JánLalinský: "Finally, we assert that the Lorentz gauge is the only
physical gauge for observing vector potential radiation.
Other gauges are mathematical manipulations that result in a
velocity of propagation different from c; this is untenable…
they must be dismissed as unphysical." page 4 of the Zimmerman's original paper.

Comment: The paper is terrible. Perhaps the experiment was better. I do not see any convincing argument for the above claim.